# D3 js grouped bar chart position

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I use the tutorial from http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/3/. While I want to have a grouped bar chart like [image: grouped bar chart]
<sub>(source: [academyhealth.org](http://www.academyhealth.org/ahrq/elders/graph2.jpg))</sub>
.Followed the answer of my last question, i create two data sets but the y-position of the second data sets can never be set as same as the first one. Here is code snippet that set position of bar chart.

```
var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
      .data(data_1)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + (i * barWidth+60) + ", -100)"; });
```

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.chart rect {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.chart text {
  fill: white;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  text-anchor: middle;
}

</style>
<svg class="chart"></svg>
<svg class="chart_1"></svg>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>


var data = [4, 5];


var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0])
    .domain([0, d3.max(data)]);

var chart = d3.select(".chart")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);


  var barWidth_ = width /data.length;
  var barWidth = barWidth_/2;

  var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + i * barWidth + ",0)"; });

  bar.append("rect")
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d); })
      .attr("width", barWidth -200);

  bar.append("text")
      .attr("x", barWidth / 2)
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d) + 3; })
      .attr("dy", ".75em")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });



var data_1 = [1000, 1000];
var width = 960,
    height = 500;


var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0])
    .domain([0, d3.max(data_1)]);

var chart = d3.select(".chart_1")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);


  var barWidth_ = width /data_1.length;
  var barWidth = barWidth_/2;

  var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
      .data(data_1)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + (i * barWidth+60) + ", -100)"; });

  bar.append("rect")
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d); })
      .attr("width", barWidth -200);

  bar.append("text")
      .attr("x", barWidth / 2)
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d) + 3; })
      .attr("dy", ".75em")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });



</script>
```

Here is the jsfiddle code here
http://jsfiddle.net/tw981/BDLt6/

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051)?

Comment: Yes, but is it just one line code that can make my current solution work?

Comment: Well you're doing something completely different, so I doubt that a one line change will suffice.